# Appium for iOS: How to verify attributes that changes instantly

Tags: ios7, appium

I have a button which has only attribute "value" that changes from null to 1 when it is clicked. But within a fraction of time it restored to value null . During that fraction of time it gets highlighted.

I am retrieving the attribute value and asserting that it is "1" to verify that it is getting selected when tapped on it. But the time when my next command fetches value attribute , it restored to null.

Any work around for this ? Any way to stop appium to load page source after execution of a command or fetching the value attribute at the same time/instantly while clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  Maybe your developer could do something for you like value==1 means Clicked, value < 0 means Not Clicked, so on each click it temporarily goes to 1, then to -2, -3, -4...?  Or maybe another element on the screen could change when it is clicked, signaling that the button was clicked.  Not an elegant solution, I know.  Such is automation.